# ggplot: set axis to a certain range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am desperately trying to set the scale range from 1 to 5.
I was trying to use `ylim()`, `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,5,1))` and `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,5))`. How can this be done? Thanks for help!

```r
n <- 10000

test <- data.frame(value = sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   item = sample(c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6"), size = n, replace = TRUE)) 
                   
test %>%
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean, group = grp, fill = grp)) +
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1, 5)) +
    coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* put the `ylim` inside `coord_flip`

```r
test %>%
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean, group = grp, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

Even better, *don't* use `coord_flip` at all. The default behaviour of `geom_col` is to make the bars horizontal if you have a categorical y axis and numeric x axis. I always find `coord_flip` confusing when applying scales and themes, so you can put `item` on the y axis, `mean` on the x axis, and stick to using `xlim` in `coord_cartesian` instead:

```r
test %>%
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = item, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

Even better is to use `stat = "summary"` inside `geom_bar`, so you don't need to summarize your data frame at all:

```r
ggplot(test, aes(x = value, y = item, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'summary', position = 'dodge') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `limits` in `scale_x_continuous` like this:

```r
n <- 10000

test <- data.frame(value = sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   item = sample(c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6"), size = n, replace = TRUE)) 
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean, group = grp, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,5,1), limits = c(0, 5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think this will work if you set the limits to (1, 5), as in the question Quinten.